# Unlock opportunity object during approval process

Tags: apex, community, approval-process, locking

I have an approval process for Opportunity object. In the beginning of the approval process the Opportunity is locked and in the end the Opportunity object is unlocked. What I want to achieve is the Opportunity object to be unlocked throughout the entire approval process. Could you please advise how this can be done and provide relevant example.

Comment: I can't find the record checkbox in the approval process action steps there is no such record lock checkbox. Could you please send instructions how to navigate to the record lock checkbox.

Comment: ahh sorry about that.. I guess you need to use apex code to unlock your record. so when your record get submitted update any field that will fire the trigger and in trigger code use `Approval.unlock(accts, false)` method for unlock the record.. check this https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_apex_approval_locks_unlocks.htm

Comment: Indeed I need an apex code to unlock the Opportunity record but I can't find the apex class which is invoked when the approval process is submitted. Could you please advise how to find the apex class where I can implement the unlock method?

Comment: Yeah sure.. so basically when you submit your record for approval. Are you updating field using approval process action ? if not then create a field like status picklist in that object. When you submit for approval update that picklist like submitted. When you update the picklist that will fire the update trigger. In trigger check if status == submitted then unlock that record .. let me know if this will work or not.

Comment: Why do you keep sabotaging your own posts? Please stop.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because STOP Deleting your content. Its more about principle than the substance of your questions but still.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That defeats the whole purpose of having an approval process and I dont think Salesoforce allows or is suggested way of doing approvals in Salesforce